# How to change currency by changing the URL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a list of items on my website with prices on it. Is it possible to change the currency prices by changing the URL content?

Is it possible if e.g. `website.com/?currency=usd` then if you change it to `website.com/?currency=aud`, it'll also change currency displayed and convert the price based on the currency on the URL? All the pages on my website are all in HTML format.

I apologize for a noob question because I have no idea how to do it. I found some answers on the internet, but I couldn't understand them. Hope you could help me out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the question I marked as duplicate for how to read values from the URL. From there you can implement your logic to read the correct currency value.

Comment: You have "php" tagged, so if you are actually wanting to use PHP for it (even though you say site is only html), you can read it from the $_GET variable. Hope it helps.